# How do you like to organize the docker-compose.yml for large projects?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, code-organization

For a system with mixed languages, multiple repos, and disparate build chains; how do you like to organize your docker-compose.yml to facilitate the various teams working on the system?

For example;

- repo1: a react application implementing a management UI
- repo2: a python application implementing an API
- repo3: an iOS application implementing client(s)
- additional services used by one or more of the former system components

  - redis
  - postgres
  - asynchronous workers (e.g. celery, Amazon SQS, ...)
  - Document store (e.g. Mongo, Couch, ...)

---

## What is your approach for Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml file(s)?  Do you use another repo just for the docker infrastructure?

Comment: At that scale I start looking at other larger solutions.  Kubernetes is an investment, but supports a one-resource-per-file model, and there are a couple of straightforward ways for developers to deploy some or all of the system isolated from the production environment and other developers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  I'll look into Kubernetes.